# How do you filter the display of traits in Visual Studio Test Explorer?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, test-explorer

I'm using Visual Studio's Test Explorer with Machine.Specifications and would like to organize the tests by the Subject attribute.  When organizing tests by trait, all the tests are grouped by Subject, but they are ALSO listed under the ClassName trait.  That is to say, all tests with a Subject attribute will be displayed twice: once under the ClassName trait and once under the Subject trait.  I would like to only display the Subject traits.

The search filter appears to allow you to show/hide tests which have a given filter (e.g. Search: Trait:"Subject", or -Trait:"Subject"), but it doesn't seem to be possible to only view tests under a specific trait.  Is this possible?

Comment: Did you fix this issue? Visual studio test explorer can group by traits - The explorer will sort the list based on the tagged traits.

Comment: I don't know that I ever worked through this.  I almost exclusively use Resharper's test runner ... as I've always found it to be far superior to VS's built-in runner.  I was likely trying to figure this out for a co-worker who didn't want to install Resharper.  Haven't looked at VS's runner in more recent versions to know if there have been any improvements.